# WQL like & not like multiple values combination

Tags: sccm, wql

I want to use a WQL query to filter out devices in an SCCM device collection with the following criteria: Name contains CS, MON, AVS, WUG, FS or IBM and not DR or LON

Here's my query:

```
select SMS_R_SYSTEM.ResourceID,SMS_R_SYSTEM.ResourceType,SMS_R_SYSTEM.Name,SMS_R_SYSTEM.SMSUniqueIdentifier,SMS_R_SYSTEM.ResourceDomainORWorkgroup,SMS_R_SYSTEM.Client from SMS_R_System where SMS_R_System.Name like "%CS%" or SMS_R_System.Name like "%MON%" or SMS_R_System.Name like "%AVS%" or SMS_R_System.Name like "%WUG%" or SMS_R_System.Name like "%FS%" and SMS_R_System.Name not like "%DR%" and SMS_R_System.Name not like "%LON%"
```

I've also tried the 'not' operator before the field name:

```
...and not SMS_R_System.Name like "%DR%" and not SMS_R_System.Name like "%LON%"
```

However, the 'not' operator gets ignored either way.

It works fine if I just used one 'like' and one 'not like' argument together but adding any additional 'like' values seems to stop this from working.

I'm pretty sure what I'm trying to do can be done but am obviously missing something. Any ideas?

Comment: So of course it is hard to say from the way you wrote it but the way you are putting the not in the middle of the ORs I kinda have the feeling you are missing a parenthesis here?

Comment: If you look at the WQL examples for SCCM queries on the web, none have parenthesis for 'like' operators.....None that I've seen anyway, however, you can see from my post that I've also tried it with the 'not' operator next to 'like' also

Comment: what I mean is from a pure point of boolean logic "CS, MON, AVS, WUG, FS or IBM and not DR or LON" is not the same as "CS, MON, AVS, WUG, FS or IBM and not (DR or LON)" so basically what happens if you really want it without paranthesis is that like every or if one of the positive ones is true the "or not like lon" thing is ignored because "true or false" is always true. So you need either a parenthesis or you have to write "and not like DR AND not like LON" because eliminating a parenthesis with a not changes all ors to ands. At least if I understood your intention correctly.

Comment: Ok, I understand. It was actually pasted from a subsequent test of operator using 'or' with a 'not'. My original query used 'and' for both and have now updated the original post to reflect this. I've removed the second 'and not...like' rule to simplify testing. Even with just the one present, it still get's ignored. Seems that an 'and not...like' will only work when only one 'like' rule is present. I've resorted to a direct rule for now but ideally would like to use a query.

Comment: It is definitely possible to have multiple "and not ... like" rules, I tried it in my environment. I still think you just have a problem that can be solved with more parentheses exactly around the parts you want to be evaluated first. Or you might also have a problem with the inherent logic. Sometimes ors do not really work in the way we first think they do when we come up with the logic in our head. First design the query for the one half and test what set comes up and then the other one and then compare if the set you really want is really the intersection or if the sets are already wrong.

Comment: Ahh spot on. I've used parenthesis and it's working as intended now. I'll post the answer so it clear. Thanks very much for your help Syberdoor.

Comment: No problem, glad it works now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using advice provided by Syberdoor I managed to get this working by using parenthesis around the like and not like operators effectively creating one like and one not like group rather than many:

```
select SMS_R_SYSTEM.ResourceID,SMS_R_SYSTEM.ResourceType,SMS_R_SYSTEM.Name,SMS_R_SYSTEM.SMSUniqueIdentifier,SMS_R_SYSTEM.ResourceDomainORWorkgroup,SMS_R_SYSTEM.Client from SMS_R_System where (SMS_R_System.Name like "%CS%" or SMS_R_System.Name like "%MON%" or SMS_R_System.Name like "%AVS%" or SMS_R_System.Name like "%WUG%" or SMS_R_System.Name like "%FS%" or SMS_R_System.Name like "%IBM%") and not (SMS_R_System.Name like "%DR%" or SMS_R_System.Name like "%LON%")
```

Spot on thanks.